# Does a nunit test case need static main method?

Tags: c#, nunit

```
[TestFixture]
public class CalciTest
{
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        calci calculator = new calci();
        add_Test();
        sub_Test();
    }

    [Test]
    public void add_Test()
    {

        int sum = calculator.add(5, 6);
        Assert.AreEqual(sum, 11);
    }
    [Test]
    public void sub_Test()
    {
        int diff = calculator.sub(15, 6);
        Assert.AreEqual(diff, 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: What test framework do you use? Looks like NUnit. Here, you don't need a main method as an entry point but a unit test runner that loads the unit test assembly.

Comment: `Does a nunit test case need static main method?` No. It does not need it. It should not have it.

Comment: What happened when you tried running the tests with and without the main method?  What happened in each case?

Comment: Also, please note the TestFixture is optional since NUnit 2.5 for non-generic and non-parametrized fixtures: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute.

Answer (score 1):

According to NUnit framework documentation, you don't need a static main method. You just need mark your class as [TestFixture] and mark your methods with attribute [Test] or [TestCase] or [TestCaseSource].

After building your project you should be able to see your test in test explorer.

If you use a Visual Studio as IDE you could find it in Test -> Window -> Test Explorer.

More details you can read at github NUnit website: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnit-Documentation;

And by the way, it is a bad practice use static method to call all tests.